# How to add timer for cart?

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, cart-rule

I want to add timer to cart.

If item is added to cart it will remain in cart only for specific time say 15 min also product quantity will reduce as per quantity added in cart.

Customer should begin payment process within this time else automatically item remove from cart and product quantity will as it is before.

Comment: the simplest way is to add a cron that checks the date when the item was added to the cart and remove it if it's older than X minutes

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of an extension that has this sort of functionality.

If I was going to implement it, Magento stores each each item in the

```
sales_flat_quote_item
```

table, and they're managed by the `sales/quote_item` model. (`Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')`)

Writing a cron job or adding an event listener that scans this table and compares the current time to the `updated_at` fields would be the way to go.  The entire implementation, particularly its effect on the user interface and/or experience goes beyond one simple Stack Exchange question.